# Sending BLOB to nodejs API results in empty body on server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, blob, axios

I need to send BLOB to the server in order to make an image on same.

I am using `axios` on reactJs client and sending data by using this code.

```
 /**
 * Returns PDF document.
 *
 */
getPDF = (blob) =>
{
    let formatData = new FormData();
    formatData.append('data', blob);

    return axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://172.18.0.2:8001/export/pdf',
        headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' },
        data: {
            blob: formatData
        }
    }).then(response => {
        return {
            status: response.status,
            data: response.data
        }
    })
}
```

I tried to `console.log` this **`blob`** value on client and there is regular data.

But on server request body is empty.

```
/**
 * Exports data to PDF format route.
 */
app.post('/export/pdf', function (request, response) {
    console.log(request.body.blob);


    response.send('ok');

});
```

If I remove headers still empty body when sending blob, but if I remove blob and send some string, a server receives data.

But when the blob is sent server has an empty body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NodeJS` natively does not handle `multipart/form-data` so you have to use external module eg :- `multer`

Code Example(Not Tested):

```
var upload = multer({ dest: __dirname + '/public/uploads/' });
var type = upload.single('upl');

/**
 * Exports data to PDF format route.
 */
app.post('/export/pdf', type, function (request, response) {
    // Get the blob file data
    console.log(request.file);
    response.send('ok');

});
```

you can read about `multer` [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)
I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `body-parser`?

`body-parser` doesn't handle `multipart` bodies, which is what `FormData` is submitted as.
Instead, use a module like [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

```
let multer = require('multer');
let upload = multer();

app.post('/export/pdf', upload.fields([]), (req, res) => {
  let formData = req.body;
  console.log('Data', formData);
  res.status(200).send('ok');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 problems that I had to solve for this. 1 firebase functions has a bug that doesn't allow multer. 2 you may be getting a blob back from response.blob() and that doesn't seem to produce a properly formatted blob for firebase functions either.